# Uniform distribution- independent random variable max and min

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $X,Y \sim U_{[-1,1]}$ are independent random variables. Let us define $U=\max (X,Y)$ and $V=\min(X,Y)$. Are random variables $U,V$ independent ?

Comment: Intuitively, does knowing the value of $U$ tell you any information about $V$?

Comment: I think, that yes.

Comment: I think, that $U,V$ are dependent, but I have problem, because I trying find an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(V > 0) = P(X > 0 \wedge Y > 0) = 0.5 \times 0.5 = 0.25$

However, $P(V > 0 | U = 0) = 0$, since $U = 0 \implies X \leq 0 \wedge Y \leq 0$.

i.e. the distribution of $V | U$ is not the same as the unconditional distribution of $V$, so they are not independent.

Comment: $P(V > 0) = P(X > 0 \color{red}{\wedge} Y > 0) = 0.5 \times 0.5 = 0.25$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes - the event $min(X, Y) > 0$ is the same as the event $X, Y > 0$, i.e. the minimum is greater than zero if both of the values are greater.